# .Net build is failing due to invalid applicationHost.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, msbuild

Folks,

Am trying to run a build using the below command line however there is a prompt everytime which is causing trouble. I have to address this manually and cannot run automated builds.

```
$currentScriptPath = (pwd).Path
$solution = "$($currentScriptPath)\foobar_Msi.sln"
$project = "$($currentScriptPath)\foobarSetup\foobarSetup.vdproj"
$BuildLog = "$($currentScriptPath)\buildlog.txt"
$devEnvCom = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"
$devEnvExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$PackagePath = "$($currentScriptPath)\ReleasePackage"
.
.
.
& $devEnvCom $solution /project $project /Build release /Out $BuildLog
```

> An error occured when applying the IIS Express settings to server URL
>   'http://localhost:2943/' for project 'Foobar.UI'. You may have to
>   manually edit the applicationHost.config file and make the changes for
>   your site to run correctly

I cleared IISAppsettings in document, tried non-interactive command line arguments, changed the binding in build servers applicationHost.Config file and nothing works.

Comment: See if this is related to ur problem ? https://forums.asp.net/t/2010751.aspx?Opening+Project+in+VS+produces+reports+IIS+Express+error+

Comment: link doesnt open up

Comment: It does for me. One gist of it is to change port number and try.

Comment: This question might have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748878/visual-studio-command-line-build-pauses-with-warning-message-box/43749135

Answer (score 0):

On your development machine, copy/move the solution to a local path that exactly matches the one it will be in when the automated build is run. Open the solution in Visual Studio 2012, Save All, and add the hidden `[solution path].VS\applicationHost.config` to source control.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help if the path varies on the build farm.