# Visual Studio command-line build pauses with warning message box

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

Our automated build process is as follows:

- The build script fetches the latest version of the repository into a clean directory
- It runs the build using the following command line command

> devenv SolutionFile.sln /rebuild "ServerDeployment|Any CPU" | out-file -FilePath $BuildOutputFile

I want this to run unattendend.

But then the build pauses to display a modal dialog:

> An error occurred when applying the IIS Express settings to server URL 'http://localhost:60143/' for project 'CMS.Website'. You may have to manually edit the applicationHost.config file and make the changes for your site to run correctly.

I have to press OK for the build to continue. This is no longer a working unattended build.

I see that Visual Studio has automatically generated a file `.vs\applicationhost.config` in my build folder.

I compared this file with the file `.vs\applicationhost.config` in my development folder. I can see the version of the file in my development folder (which doesn't cause errors) has an extra `site` entry under the node: `//configuration/system.applicationHost/sites`

[image]

How can I make this message box go away? Obviously I don't care if this runs on IIS Express or not, because I'm performing a build to be deployed on a different server.

Possible solutions (that I don't particularly like) are:

- Check the file .vs\applicationhost.config into the repository, so it gets checked out as part of the build rather than regenerated
- Modify my build script so it copies the template file from `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config` and then modifies this XML file to manually add the new `site` entry

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the debug settings were stored as part of the Web Application's `.csproj` file (which is part of the checked-in repository).

It should be stored as part of the `.csproj.user` file (which does not get checked in).

In my project settings I needed to make sure that 'Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)' was unchecked.

[image]

Once I unchecked this setting the automated build ran from start to finish without presenting a modal message box.